# Ugly fonts in Clion on Ubuntu

Tags: java, fonts

I did this [Ugly fonts in Java applications on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510099/ugly-fonts-in-java-applications-on-ubuntu) but my CLion still looks very ugly: [image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try to install the `openjdk-7` with `fontfix` and `set CL_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64` before start Clion.

Comment: What exactly did you do to reach the current state? The linked questions has multiple suggested answers. In addition, the resolution of the screenshot in your question is too small to recognise any potentially "ugly" font rendering. Please post a larger version of it. It would also help to post the output of `dpkg-query -l openjdk-\*-jre | awk '($1=="ii"){print($2)}' | xargs apt-cache policy`, `readlink -f "$(which java)"` and `java -version`.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Ugly fonts in Netbeans - How can i make it use the system font?](/q/32624/175814)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't use nor do I have CLion, but I would assume that the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/help/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html) would still apply.

According to that page, you should:

1. Open **Settings**, and under the **Editor** node, click *Colors & Fonts*.
2. Select the desired scheme from the Scheme name drop-down list.
3. If you need to change certain settings of the selected scheme, create its copy. To do that, click Save as button, and type the new scheme name in the dialog box.

[image]

3. Under the *Colors and Fonts* node, change the font families used in the editor and in the console:

   - Define font family for the editor and console. When you just open the **Font** or **Console Fonts** pages under the *Colors and Fonts* node, CLion displays **Editor Font** area where you can configure primary and secondary fonts, their size and line spacing.

   [image]
4. Under the Colors and Fonts node, open pages to configure specific color preferences and font types for the different supported languages and CLion components.

Now, those images come directly from that page I linked (as do the instructions) and are from Windows, but the menus and settings should be laid out the same for Ubuntu.